# Angular2localization vs ng2-translate differences

Tags: javascript, angular, localization, internationalization, translation

What are the differences between the two libraries I should be aware of? Is there a general community consensus yet as to which one to use? Most of the posts talk about ng2-translate but they seem similar and angular2localization seems like it has more features.

The main differences I see is that

angular2localization supports currency and time,

ng2-translate allows you to create templates that take a value into it. But this doesn't seem a big issue as you can just use the variable in the code instead of the template...

Is there anything I'm missing out in my decision?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am the developer of [angular2localization](https://github.com/robisim74/angular2localization). I started this library as an experimental app for translation when Angular 2 was still in early alpha versions because Angular 2 did not support translation (and still does not support in the rc.5), and even the localization of numbers and dates.
[ng2-translate](https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate) is more popular and has more contributors: as ng-translate, it was created to provide the translation.
At the moment, I think that the main differences are these:

**Angular 2 Final release** - Native

- *Messages*: Html attribute, Message ID
- *File formats*: XLIFF, XMB/XTB
- *No bootstrap (when language changes)*: no
- *Getting the translation in component class*: ?
- *Numbers*: pure pipe via Intl
- *Dates*: pure pipe via Intl
- *Validation*: -

**ng2-translate** - External library

- *Messages*: impure pipe
- *File formats*: JSON
- *No bootstrap (when language changes)*: yes
- *Getting the translation in component class*: yes
- *Numbers*: -
- *Dates*: -
- *Validation*: -

**angular2localization** - External library

- *Messages*: pure pipe
- *File formats*: JSON
- *No bootstrap (when language changes)*: yes
- *Getting the translation in component class*: yes
- *Numbers*: pure pipe via Intl
- *Dates*: pure pipe via Intl
- *Validation*: numbers validation

I invite anyone interested to correct and update this table. Cc @Olivier